# Virtual functions with same name but different arguments and return types

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, virtual-functions

I was asked this question in an interview. My answer was (3 and 3.6)(wrong).
Please explain how my understanding is wrong

My thinking was that pointer *bd* will point to the _vptr of derived class vtable.

Vtable of Derived class will contain 2 functions

```
double func(double) // ----->points to Derived::func()
int func(int)       // ----->points to Base::func()
```

Hence,

```
bd->func(2)   // will call Base::func() i.e int func(int)
bd->func(2.3) // will call Derived::func() i.e double func(double)
```

Please explain how my understanding is wrong.
Also, explain the case when `Base::func()` is not `virtual`.
In that case, there will be no vtable right? How will be function calls be resolved?

```
#include <iostream>    
using namespace std;

class Base
{
private:
    /* data */
public:
    Base(/* args */){};
    ~Base(){};

    //int func(int i)     getting same answer regardless of virtual
    virtual int func(int i)
    {
        cout << "Base func()" << endl;
        return i+1;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    Derived(/* args */){};
    ~Derived(){};

    double func(double d)
    {
        cout << "Derived func()" << endl;
        return d+1.3;
    }
};

int main() {
    Base* bd = new Derived();
    cout << bd->func(2) << endl;
    cout << bd->func(2.3) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Expected output:

```
Base func()
3
Derived func()
3.6

Actual output:
Base func()
3
Base func()
3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no function taking a `double` in `Base`. And all you have is a pointer to `Base`. So the 2.3 is truncated to the `int` value `2` and `Base::func(int i)` is called.

`Derived::func(double d)` is not in play at all in this code.

It doesn't matter that `func` is `virtual` in `Base`, since the `func` in `Derived` does not `override` it (the signatures don't match). Adding the `override` keyword to `Base::func` will make that clear instantly as a compiler error.

Comment: Doesn't `bd` vptr point to the derived class virtual table? If yes, then `Derived::func() ` should be called on `bd->func(2.3)`.

Comment: @mohit The static type of `bd` is `Base*`, so initially you'll hit `Base::func`. That function is `virtual`, so if there *was* an overriding function in the class matching the *dynamic* type (`Derived`) it would be called. But there is no such function since `Derived::func` does not actually `override` `Base::func`. So `Base::func` is called.

Comment: At compile time, `bd` points to Base. so 2.3 is being cast to an integer 2 at compile time and resolved to `Base::func()`. Hence, at runtime, the program will search for an overriding version for `int func(int)` (because it already considers `bd->func(2.3)` to be of type `int func(int)` at compile time) which it will not find in the derived class. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: No. That's not how it works. I don't know how to explain better than I already did. Maybe someone else can.

Comment: ok. no problem. thanks for all the help